# How to draw density plot and bar plot together using Python?

Tags: python, count, histogram, heatmap, scatter

Let's say I have such data:

```
c1=pd.DataFrame({'Num1':[1,2,3,4],
                 'Counts':[5,1,7,10]})
c2=pd.DataFrame({'Num2':[3,4,5,6],
                 'Counts':[3,5,2,8]})
c12=pd.DataFrame({'Num1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
                  'Num2':[3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6],
                  'Counts':[2,3,1,3,4,5,1,6,7,2,5,10,4,8,2,9]})
```

c1 has Num1, Counts means how many times the numbers in c1 occurs in the data set. For example, 1 occurs 5 times. So does c2. c12 means how many times Num1 and Num2 occurs. For example, Num1=1 and Num2=3 occurs 2 times.

I want to draw such a plot:

[image]

x axis is Num1 in c1 and y axis is Num2. Bar plot means the Counts in c1 or c2. The scatter plot means the Counts in c12. In scatter plot, the point size is the counts.

How can I use Python to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine three plots in `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
fig.add_axes([0, 0, 0.8, 0.8])
plt.scatter(x=c12['Num1'], y=c12['Num2'], s=c12['Counts'] * 20)
plt.xlabel('Num1')
plt.ylabel('Num2')
plt.xticks(range(10))
plt.yticks(range(10))
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.xlim(0, 10)

# first barplot
fig.add_axes([0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2])
plt.bar(x=c1['Num1'], height=c1['Counts'])
plt.axis('off')
plt.xlim(0, 10)

# second barplot
fig.add_axes([0.8, 0, 0.2, 0.8])
plt.barh(y=c2['Num2'], width=c2['Counts'])
plt.axis('off')
plt.ylim(0, 10)
```

[image]